# Непонятное поведение флага CF

Tags: ассемблер

Допустим есть часть кода:

```
mov al, 12
mov bl, 4
sub al, bl
```

При этом флаг CF = 0, но по-моему должен быть равным 1, поскольку операция вычитания реализована на операции сложения и процессор не знает что мы даем ему на вход, будь-то числа знаковые или беззнаковые, он просто выполняет свою работу.

То есть код выше эквивалентен следующему:

1. Занести в регистр al значение 12, то есть 0000 1100
2. Занести в регистр bl значение 4, то есть 0000 0100
3. Далее идет операция вычитание, поскольку первый операнд положительный, то преобразований в дополнительный код нету. Поскольку второй тоже положительный, то тоже преобразований нету, но поскольку выполняется операция вычитания, то второй операнд переводится в дополнительный код и процессор выполняет операцию сложения (вычитание реализовано сложением), то есть:

   ```
   12: 0000 1100
   -4: 1111 1100



   12 - 4 = 12 + (-4) = 0000 1100 + 1111 1100 = 1 0000 1000
   ```

То есть, результат мы получили верный - 8, но CF = 0, если продебажить. Почему так? Единичка, что вышла за разрядную сетку помещается в CF, но CF = 0.

Answer (score 3):

Не стоит мудрить и усложнять.

Результат правильный и вполне логичный.

Флаг `CF` выставляется в случае переполнения при сложении, либо заёма при вычитании, при этом рассматривать операцию надо естественным интуитивным способом, как делается в математике.
Рассмотрим сложение:

```
al = 12
bl = 4
result = 16
max(al) = 255 - максимум для регистра
```

Если бы результат сложения был бы больше 255, то флаг был бы поднят.

Если при вычитании бы было так:

```
al = 4
bl = 12
```

Потребовался бы заём, соответственно, флаг переноса был бы установлен в 1.

На интуитивном уровне схема такая:

- не выходят ли разряды за разрядную сетку при сложении
- достаточно ли единиц у уменьшаемого при вычитании